# Copy output of a JavaScript variable to the clipboard (multi-line)

Tags: javascript

This question is very similar to the following question posted here [Copy output of a JavaScript variable to the clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33855641/copy-output-of-a-javascript-variable-to-the-clipboard) , but there are a few things unanswered, which i cant figure out. This approach works, but my test var is actually a string on multiple lines, because it contains a few html tags and once copied, each tag with information must appear separate on a line. However once i copy it, on the clipboard this gets copied all in 1 line. How can i modify this in order to copy it properly on multiple lines?

```
testingVarTest(testvar);

function testingVarTest(testvar) {
    var dummy = document.createElement("input");
    document.body.appendChild(dummy);
    dummy.setAttribute("id", "dummy_id");
    document.getElementById("dummy_id").value=testvar;
    dummy.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.body.removeChild(dummy);
}
```

Comment: inputs do not have new lines. So use a textarea?

Comment: Omg tnx man. I missed this detail. This works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments, an input doesn't have line breaks, so just replace `input` with `textarea` in your code