# How do I create a copy button for Javascript outputs that have italics/bold?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a Copy button that copies the text from a Javascript output. I have looked at [Copy output of a JavaScript variable to the clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33855641/copy-output-of-a-javascript-variable-to-the-clipboard) but it does not work for me since my output contains italics and bold characters. Using that method generates   and   in the copied text.

I would like the text to be copied to remain italicized/bold. If anyone has any ideas or suggestions please let me know! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please add your own current html/css/js [tried so far]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript copy rich text contents to clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934656/javascript-copy-rich-text-contents-to-clipboard)

Comment: @alimbaronia thank you for the link. It provided me with the solution I needed.