# Pressing button in row of table to copy cell to clipboard - Javascript

Tags: javascript, button, html-table

I was wondering if a guru could help me out with this one.  I have a table with a button in each row.  After pressing the copy button, it should copy the verbiage that is in cell 2 of that row.  I am able to get an alert to come up, but I need it to copy to clip board, so a user can paste it to another application.  Also, this method works in chrome, but not  IE11.  Is there a method that works for both?  Thanks so much!

```js
var a = document.getElementsByClassName('otherButton');

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  a[i].addEventListener('click', function() {

    var b = this.parentNode.parentNode.cells[1].textContent;
    alert(b);

  });
}
```

```html
<table id="somerow">
  <tr>
    <th>CustomerNr</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Cigarettes Inc</td>
    <td>Rambo</td>
    <td><button class="otherButton">Copy</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>Razor</td>
    <td>David</td>
    <td><button class="otherButton">Copy</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>H&M</td>
    <td>Samuel Adams</td>
    <td><button class="otherButton">Copy</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific.  My code above does not work in IE11 that uses the alert.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this [copy-output-of-a-javascript-variable-to-the-clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33855641/copy-output-of-a-javascript-variable-to-the-clipboard) but be aware that [execCommand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) is deprecated. If your project allows external dependecies, you can use [clipboardjs](https://clipboardjs.com/)

```js
var a = document.getElementsByClassName('otherButton');

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  a[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var b = this.parentNode.parentNode.cells[1].textContent;
    copyToClipboard(b);
    alert(b);
  });
}

function copyToClipboard(text) {
  var dummy = document.createElement("textarea");
  document.body.appendChild(dummy);
  dummy.value = text;
  dummy.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.body.removeChild(dummy);
}
```

```html
<table id="somerow">
  <tr>
    <th>CustomerNr</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Cigarettes Inc</td>
    <td>Rambo</td>
    <td><button class="otherButton">Copy</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>Razor</td>
    <td>David</td>
    <td><button class="otherButton">Copy</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>H&M</td>
    <td>Samuel Adams</td>
    <td><button class="otherButton">Copy</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Good stuff Mara.  Thanks for this.  This works on Chrome, but not IE11.  I was having issues originally with the javascript at the top of page without the copytoclipboard code.  Is there a way to accomplish this in Chrome and IE11.  Unfortunately, my project does not allow for external dependencies.  Thanks again for everybody's time.

Comment: I ran the debugger in IE11 and this is the error I get.  Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementsByClassName' I am not understanding this because I have used getElementsByClassName in IE in other projects.

Comment: @RickD well.. if your peoject suports, you can use `jQuery` :-? or implement `getElementByClassName` in your peoject beacuse IE doesnot know about it ( read more here: [getelementsbyclassname-doesnt-work-in-old-internet-explorers-like-ie6-ie7-i](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584635/getelementsbyclassname-doesnt-work-in-old-internet-explorers-like-ie6-ie7-i) )