# Uncaught TypeError: url.select is not a function attr copy

Tags: jquery

Good day,
I have a problem with attr and copying to the clipboard I use this code

```
$( ".copy-clip" ).click(function() {
            var url = $(this).attr("data-url");
            url.select();
            document.execCommand("copy");
            alert( "Done" );
        });
```

and the console shows me this error i tried sel () and still have the same problem.

index.php?q=test:240 Uncaught TypeError: url.select is not a function

Comment: `url` holds a string value. A string does not have a `select()` method. If you're attempting to copy a string to the clipboard, then this has been covered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46118025/519413